# Maximum number of members per Google Group

Tags: google-groups

I have 600 members in our club.  Currently I have created 6 Google Groups and have to send out 6 GG emails at least twice a week and adding and updating is a pain.  Is there any way to have 600 people in one group for free or do I have to have the Business version?

Answer (score 1):

I have a google group (not business) with about 2000 members. Why do you think you are limited to 100? You can direct add only 100 per day - but the next day you can add 100 more. Or you can invite all of them to join, if they know how.